# How to handle Authorization in a Delphi Webbroker Apache module?

Tags: delphi, indy, webbroker

I am working on an Apache module (WebBroker Apache dll) and would like to handle
Authorization: Basic

Unfortunately TWebRequest does not populate AuthPassword and AuthUser.
Any idea where can i find them?

Comment: `TWebRequest` does not have `AuthPassword`/`AuthUser` properties. Did you mean the [`Authorization`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Web.HTTPApp.TWebRequest.Authorization) property? If not, please clarify your issue with more detail.

Comment: Remy, i mean the Authorization property sent in the header of the HTTP request.
This property which i would like to extract from the header and process, but i cannot see how to do that.

Comment: Problem solved.
Unfortunately i have tried with Delphi 10 Seattle which does not populate the Authorization property correctly.
As Remy pointed to the Alexandria's help page i gave it a shot to try it in Alexandria as well. It turned out it does that as expected, so the problem was solved somewhere in the releases after Seattle.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Indy's `IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge` has populated `TWebRequest.Authorization` since way before Seattle.

Comment: I went down the rabbit hole and saw that indy correctly process the auth field and populate user and password fields as well. It is clearly Embarcadero’s implementation bug. I will compare the source between the 10 and 11 to see where is the problem as i want to use Seattle for this.

Comment: In case you're interested, I have an alternative Delphi+web-platform that also has an Apache httpd module: https://github.com/stijnsanders/xxm/tree/master/Delphi/apache

Comment: Thanks. I will surely check it out.